# How to identify Java objects that are ready for GC?

Tags: java, scala, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I'm profiling a Java/Scala API as we are experiencing OutOfMemoryError sometimes.
It's a quite old API with a lot of connections to/from other APIs.

After performing a few calls to the API, this is the memory allocation(I'm using IntelliJ built-in profiler):
[image]

If I leave it there and don't do anything, that memory never goes down, but at the moment I click on the button "Perform GC", the memory goes considerably down:
[image]

So clearly there are objects that are ready to be collected but are not being collected.
How can I identify those? I tried to generate a memory snapshot but all the classes that are on the top of usage are all Java and Scala classes, not any of the classes in my API:
[image]

How can I track this down and force those object to be collected? I understand that calling a `System.gc()` is not ideal.

Comment: If `perform GC` collects them, they are not a problem, and you don't really need to identify them. When memory usage approaches limits, they _will_ be collected, so they are _not_ the ones causing your OOM problems. You need to focus on those that _remain uncollected_ after GC - they are the ones contributing to your actual long term memory footprint.